# add a list inside of a list

Tags: android

I have a list of objects and when a user clicks on one of them, I want to be able to display another list of objects that are inside that first object. Does anyone know of any tutorials or advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thats probably what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html

For example like this:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html

Or just google a bit for Tutorials for ExpandableList.

Comment: it can't be an expandable list because the user can add to the list through a button and that second list can get very long if the user wants it to, so i was thinking just one listview into the other. Thanks.

Comment: expandable list does not mean that you can't add items. you just have to  update the adapter after inserting a new item by clicking on the button. Lists are optimized for this case, if you want to implement it by yourself in a better way good luck :), only visible items will be displayed and therefore use memory, so you shouldn't worry about peformance issues